# Integration of Angular.js with a Rails with Devise authentication

Tags: devise

I'm doing an app with Rails + Angular, with authentication via Devise. I haven't understood yet how I can save in angular the information after the login, such as `user_id`. And how can I use that information with ngRoute, and be able to do the correct `GET` and `POST`

Also I don't really understand what angular-resource is doing. I've been reading a lot of blog posts and questions here but I'm still confuse about all this

Answer (score 2):

To let angular recognize current user id, what you can do is write it to javascript in layout file,

```
<% if current_user %>
  <script>
    var current_user = <%=raw current_user.to_json  %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Angular resource is javascript object wrap angular $http service, which allow you to interact with your rails resource. see the [official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)